# Efficiently finding the minimizer of a quadratic function over a finite subset of $\Bbb R^m$

Tags: optimization, computational-complexity, computational-geometry, discrete-optimization

Given matrix $A \in \Bbb R^{m \times m}$, let function $f : \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R$ defined by

$$f(x) := x^T A x$$

Suppose there are $n \gg m$ points $a_i \in \Bbb R^m$. I seek to find

$$\min_{i \in [n]} f(a_i)$$

or, at least an approximation of this this quantity with bounded error (likely depending on the geometric distribution of $\{a_i\}$) with sub-linear computational complexity in $n$. We can assume that any pre-processing of $\{a_i\}$ is free.

I have seen some results in computational geometry for Nearest Neighbour Search (NNS) which makes me think that this might be possible, with an error bound depending on something like the mutual coherence of the evaluation points, but I think to compute this exactly requires the linear complexity in $n$.

Comment: It is confusing to use uppercase for both integers and matrices. Do you agree with my edits?

Comment: Have you considered building a multivariate polynomial whose roots are the given $\{a_i\}$? Then, you have a quadratic objective and a polynomial equality constraint, and you could try to use Lagrange multipliers. I expect it to be ugly.

Comment: So this would involve solving a system of $m+1$ degree O(n) polynomials equations over $m+1$ variables... Don't see much promise in going down that rabbit hole :)

Comment: Do you have to go down that rabbit hole? How about using the dual to compute a bound?

Comment: Interesting... I will see where this takes me when I have a spare moment.